# Install packages on EMR via bootstrap actions not working in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster using EMR-6.3.1.
I am using the Python3 Kernel.

I have a very simple bootstrap script in S3:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sudo python3 -m pip install Cython==0.29.4 boto==2.49.0 boto3==1.18.50 numpy==1.19.5 pandas==1.3.2 pyarrow==5.0.0
```

These are the bootstrap logs

```bash
+ sudo python3 -m pip install Cython==0.29.4 boto==2.49.0 boto3==1.18.50 numpy==1.19.5 pandas==1.3.2 pyarrow==5.0.0
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `python3 -m pip install --user` instead.
  WARNING: The scripts cygdb, cython and cythonize are installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.7 are installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script plasma_store is installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

and

```bash
Collecting Cython==0.29.4
  Downloading Cython-0.29.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: boto==2.49.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.49.0)
Collecting boto3==1.18.50
  Downloading boto3-1.18.50-py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.19.5
  Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.8 MB)
Collecting pandas==1.3.2
  Downloading pandas-1.3.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.3 MB)
Collecting pyarrow==5.0.0
  Downloading pyarrow-5.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (23.6 MB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.6.0,>=0.5.0
  Downloading s3transfer-0.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.22.0,>=1.21.50
  Downloading botocore-1.21.65-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3==1.18.50) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas==1.3.2) (2021.1)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7.3
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas==1.3.2) (1.13.0)
Installing collected packages: Cython, python-dateutil, urllib3, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, numpy, pandas, pyarrow
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.4 boto3-1.18.50 botocore-1.21.65 numpy-1.19.5 pandas-1.3.2 pyarrow-5.0.0 python-dateutil-2.8.2 s3transfer-0.5.2 urllib3-1.26.13
```

From a notebook, importing pandas and seeing the wrong version - 1.2.3.
Further, I see pyarrow fails to import.

I've printed the import path of pandas, which python version is run, and sys.path.

```bash
import os
import pandas
import sys
print(sys.path)
print(pandas.__version__)
print(os.path.abspath(pandas.__file__))
print(os.popen('echo $PYTHONPATH').read())
print(os.popen('which python3').read())

# sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages') # if I add this, pyarrow can import
import pyarrow

['/', '/emr/notebook-env/lib/python37.zip', '/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7', '/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '', '/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget-1.0-py3.7.egg', '/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/emr-notebook/.ipython']
1.2.3
/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py


/usr/bin/python3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-aea9862499ce> in <module>
      9 
     10 # sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages') # if I add this, pyarrow can import
---> 11 import pyarrow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'
```

I found I can import pyarrow if I add `/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages` to sys.path. This seems like am improvement, but still the wrong version of pandas is imported.

I've tried:

- SSH'ing into the master node and mucking with the configuration.
- `sudo python3 -m pip install --user ...`
- `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages && sudo python3 -m pip install ...`
- `sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools && sudo python3 -m pip install ...`
- Using a pyspark kernel and running `sc.install_pypi_package("pandas==1.3.2")`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap configuration on EMR is not the last step before the cluster is WAITING and EMR Steps start running.

On my emr cluster I found that **at the least** these packages were logged as installed **after** the bootstrap configuration ran. I was having issues with numpy not upgrading.

> Python packages installed post bootstrap
>
> 2022-12-10 00:10:28,250 INFO
> main: Took 1 minute, 3 seconds and 451 milliseconds to install
> packages:
>
> [emr-scripts, emr-s3-select, aws-sagemaker-spark-sdk,
> python27-numpy, python27-sagemaker_pyspark, python37-numpy,
> python37-sagemaker_pyspark, emr-ddb, hadoop-yarn-nodemanager, docker,
> hadoop-yarn, spark-yarn-shuffle, bigtop-utils, cloudwatch-sink,
> hadoop, hadoop-lzo, emr-goodies, emrfs, hadoop-mapreduce, hadoop-hdfs,
> R-core, aws-hm-client, emr-kinesis, hadoop-hdfs-datanode,
> spark-datanucleus]

A work around to in your first cluster step to add the installition

```json
...
Steps: [

        {
            'Name': 'Install Pandas',
            "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
            "HadoopJarStep": {
                "Jar":
                "s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar",
                "Args": [
                    "s3://bucket/prefix/install_packages.sh"
                ]
            }
        },
]
```

Or if you want to use command-runner

```json
{
            "Name": "Install Pandas",
            "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
            "HadoopJarStep": {
                "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                "Args": [
                    "bash",
                    "-c",
                    " aws s3 cp s3://bucket/prefix/install.sh .; chmod +x install.sh; ./install.sh; rm install_pandas.sh "
                ]
            }
        }
```

In my example my install.sh file looks like

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -x

sudo pip3 freeze # for debugging to view the previous package versions
sudo pip3 uninstall numpy -y -v
sudo yum install python3-devel -y
sudo pip3 install boto3==1.26.26 -v
sudo pip3 install numpy==1.21.6 -v
sudo pip3 install pandas==1.3.5 -v
sudo pip3 freeze # for debugging to view the post-install package versions
```